# Generating or getting an UUID or Serial number on a chromecast receiver app

Tags: chromecast

I am currently building an application that is pretty similar to digital signage, But I would like to get some UUID or serial number on the chromecast to identify them on the serverside. This UUID/Serialnumbner would be used to determine where the chromecast is located and display the data accordingly for what is set up.

Is this even at all possible? Because all earlier questions resulted in an no and were asked a few years ago.

Solutions where I generate an UUID myself with data that is consistent on the chromecast are also fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this by using the localStorage on the chromecast and generating an token on my own.

I am currently running some tests how long that storage will persist

- It is not affected by reboots